# Codeigniter load different site content foreach possible filter selection

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, view

I have 2 input fields. In the first filter user can select category, subcategory and in the second filter user can choose product.
Upon submitting the form, the user gets redirected to the site based on his selection in the input fields.

```
    $category = $this->input->post('category', true);
    $product = $this->input->post('product', true);

    if(isset($category) && $sub_category == ''){
        redirect(base_url().'/category/'.$category);
    }elseif(isset($category) && isset($product)){
        redirect(base_url().'/category/'.$category.'/product/'.$product);
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You must select a category');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
```

Creating the urls and redirecting to them based on the user's input selection works fine. What I cannot get my head around is how to get a different view-content for each site. Each possible combination of category and product has its own content. How can I load the individual content for each possible url?
Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

try this to get url

```
$category = $this->input->post('category', true);
$product = $this->input->post('product', true);
$url =array();
if($category){
    $url[] = 'category/'.$category;
}
if($product){
    $url[] ='product/'.$product;
}
$newurl = implode('/',$url);
redirect($newurl);
```